# how to achieve SharePoint search REST API in Salesforce

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, enterprise-search

Salesforce team want to query the documents, stored in SharePoint sites .

We believe, need to expose the sharepoint search service to REST API so that the query results can be viewed directly in Salesforce.

If it is an search app, we can develop a CSOM code to build the rest api and parse JSON response from Search results.

how can we do the same in Salesforce platform?

Answer (score 2):

I think the **CMIS** is the best option to allow the applications to **interact** with `SharePoint lists and document` libraries programmatically by using the interfaces that are defined in the CMIS standard.

For more details, Check how to use and [Configure CMIS in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/10/25/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis/)